# XCode only process when enable breakpoint at one line

Tags: ios, xcode

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
while (nil == self.libraryQuery){
    self.libraryQuery = [BmobQuery queryWithClassName:@"Library"];
    sleep(2);
}
}
```

When I run the Xcode,it will jump in while and can not jump out.

But when I set a breakpoint at sleep(2),and F6 to step by step , self.libraryQuery will not nil inmediatly in the next loop.

Why?

Comment: Just a hunch, but does `[BmobQuery queryWithClassName:@"Liberary"]` run on the main thread? This sounds like a race condition. Also, sleeping the main thread is a really poor design choice. Reconsider moving this process off of the main thread using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`

Comment: Clearly, `queryWithClassName` cannot return a non-nil while the main thread is caught in a loop.